# Ganesh idol not disolving in water, next course of action

Tags: scripture, idols, ganesha

We had made small Ganesha idol from modeling clay (we are based outside India). We did the visarjana pooja and immersed the idol in a steel container containing water.

Later I realized that the idol is not disolving as the modeling clay may contain substance (plaster?) which is preventing it from disolving in water.

It is really difficult to immerse the idol in any water body (as it may not be premissible by law).

I was wondering what is the best course of action now, please advice about what is the best to immerse the idol now?

Also is there any pooja/vrutha I can perform to remedy this msiatke?

Comment: What kind or brand of "modeling clay" did you use? Those that are petroleum based aren't going to dissolve in water. Or even if water-based, if it is hardened by heating in an oven, again it isn't going to dissolve in water.

Comment: @RayButterworth Yes looks like it may not disolve in water :( Looking for alternative ways. Finding a water body to immerse the idol is going to be tricky.

Comment: Find a river nearby.